# Illustrator CS6 'Save for Web' doesn't save the image as expected

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, web-safe

I have an image 8x8 pixels as below; this is the image as I see in Adobe Illustrator CS6:

[image]

Each gray shade in upper left and lower right corners is 4x2 pixels. I would like to save this image as I see it with "Save for Web", but when I save it as PNG-24 with no anti-aliasing I get the below image:

[image]

Obviously it is very different than what I expect. What is happening here? Can anybody give me a hint about saving the image as I see it on Illustrator artboard?

NOTE: I saved the image with Photoshop without a problem. I still want to learn this weird behavior of Illustrator though.

Comment: My guess would be that that left side mid-grey box is resting on a partial pixel, therefore Illustrator is moving it to the next full pixel. I suspect you'd see the same thing if you used Pixel Preview in Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott, I made sure that they are on exact pixels. I arranged each grey box with "Transform" box. It still doesn't save properly :/.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue with an 8px by 8px square unless one of the paths is **not** on a pixel boundary. You may need to provide exact construction steps. If you turn on Pixel Preview mode, do you still see the issue?

Comment: Square, Object > Path > Split into Grid (2 rows 2 columns). Select top left quadrant - Object > Path > Split Into Grid (2 rows). Select Bottom Right quadrant - Object > Path > Splint Into Grid (2 rows). Adjust fills, save for web..... no issues anywhere.

Comment: That was really it, my artboard wasn't aligned with pixel grid. Thanks a lot. If you write it as answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make certain the artboard itself is aligned to the pixel grid. If the artboard is not sitting on an exact pixel, then the art on the artboard is not on exact pixels.

Switch to the Artboard tool and make certain the artboard is aligned to the pixel grid.